# Storing integer number to decimal slot, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, decimal

I am using MatLab. I have vector with integers [9001, 901, 91]. I want to store these in the decimal slot. I.e , want to get the vector [0.9001, 0.901, 0.91]. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:
Round up(ceil) to the next power of 10, then divide by this number. (for example round up 901 to 1000 then divide 901 by 1000 to get the result)

```
x=[10000, 901, 91]
y= x./10.^ceil(10*eps+log10(x))
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem for some integers. Ex. x=[10000, 10,  1]
Yields y=[1,1,1]

Comment: Added eps to deal with 10 multiply case